# How to solve ignore_binding error when integrating ccavenue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ccavenue

i am getting this error when i try to integrate ccavenue in rails .

any solution for this ?
Please help

[image]

i refered these links
 https://github.com/meshbrain/active_merchant_ccavenue

and when i defined my controller action i got this error
'undefined method payment_service_for', so that i referd this link, 
http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/Integrations/ActionViewHelper.html, and created payment_service_for method in the lib file.so that in that file iam getting this error. any idea?

PLease help
Any help is appreciatable